# how to extract some particular text from Postgresql DB field

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I do have one big text in Postgresql DB field called "_response" and its having a long text. i need to fetch particular text from that. i.e

```
{"bbox":[151.144543,-33.840148,151.144832,-33.839811],"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[151.144832,-33.840148],[151.144682,-33.839973],[151.144543,-33.839811]]},"properties":{"id":"000000000905012584","
```

I need to fetch only "151.144832,-33.840148" from above field in postgresql, can you please guide me. Heaps thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Assuming that `_response` is of type `text`, cast the column to `jsonb` and extract the value you want with the operators `->` or `->>`,e.g.:

```
SELECT _response::jsonb -> 'bbox' FROM yourtable;
```

If for whatever reason you want to extract the first coordinate pair of the linestring and display it as csv in a single column, consider casting the json document to a `geometry` and use the function `ST_PointN` to catch it:

```
SELECT 
 ST_X(
  ST_PointN(ST_GeomFromGeojson((_response::jsonb ->'geometry')::text),1))||','||
 ST_Y(
  ST_PointN(ST_GeomFromGeojson((_response::jsonb ->'geometry')::text),1))  
FROM yourtable;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f3e752cbedc9a6b661274f9be5f39254)

Comment: HI mate, i really appreciate your support. these both works on DB but when i use this 2nd one in power bi to fetch value from DB, it gives me error. are there any other way to extract . thanks

Comment: @Vishal what does the error message say? :-D

Comment: hi Jim, thanks for replying, error occurs due to not giving column name like as co-ordinates like that. i fixed it. thanks for your support